# Is there a tool that will let me listen to segments of a single audio file while it is still recording

Tags: audio, recording

This project encompasses accomplishing the following goals:

- Record the professor.
- Listen to past segments of recording while recording is still adding new segments.

I apologise if this is obscure. I'm trying to learn Linux and having trouble going to class because teach is a fast talker and slow walker. It's easy to miss a whole segment and then waste far too much time waiting for the next.

Comment: What is the reason you use Kali? Many other Linux distributions will be much more easy to use

Comment: Kali is optimised for expert security analysis, it is a poor general purpose OS. However if a files is being written to sequentially, then you can read it sequentially (and skip ahead, skip back, just don't run off the end). I use VLC to watch video/audio as they are being downloaded.

Comment: You can monitor a recording in progress with Audacity https://www.audacityteam.org but I don't know if you can listen to non-realtime audio. I'd start looking there. I also concur with _Romeo Ninov_ and _ctrl-alt-delor_; IMO trying to learn Linux from Kali is trying to swim with barbells. Other distros are MUCH less user-hostile

Comment: for @RomeoNinov, literally only because an alfa wifi adpater isn't in debian rolling. i'm really new so i thought adding the kali source to the list would be okay because its just a derivative. that caused me pain and i ran out of time

Comment: for @ctrl-alt-delor, vlc + a recording method is probably the quickest solution. what is so poor about kali as general purpose, though? all my problems so far have had solutions that were relatively reasonable to obtain

Comment: for @K7AAY, well you and everyone else were right when you said kali wasn't the right move. vlc and gnome-sound-recorder both chewed me out thoroughly. so many errors all at once. i'm scared to even try audacity. 

what do you think, would debian work? i'm fond of the flavor, but i can do ubuntu just as well

Comment: Debian would work as would Ubuntu. Ubuntu has its own very popular dedicated support forum here, https://askubuntu.com .

Comment: I went off Ubuntu, when it kept trying to get me to install proprietary software: I want to be free, and Ubuntu makes it harder, so I switched to Debian. (A tip to make it easier to switch, is to have a separate `/home` partition. You can leave it alone when you upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

@ctrl-alt-delor suggested vlc to read the files that are being manipulated. if i pair that with gnome-sound-recorder, i should have a quick solution.

however, this is not true on kali. lots of errors very quickly. @RomeoNinov , @ctrl-alt-delor , and @K7AAY , have all pointed out that kali is not the right distro and they are right.

I will be trying this solution with debian

**final update:** playing audio files from either sound recorder or gnome-sound-recorder results in crashes 100% of the time for debian testing. **solution:** dont open audio files with the recorder. open with vlc and everything will be okay.

**notes:**

- i used debian testing and succeeded
- kali experienced the same problems, so it likely has the same solutions.
- it probably doesnt matter what distro you are on so long as you can get vlc and an audio recorder

Comment: Debian Testing is a "testing" distribution. I'd suggest you use Debian Stable until you are more comfortable with Linux-based systems.